# Sveltekit - Is it secure to save the Firebase Auth ID Token in a Session Cookie?

Tags: javascript, firebase, cookies, firebase-authentication, svelte

I have a Sveltekit Frontend and a Node.js Backend.

For Auth (Register, Login), I use Firebase Authentication.

Now, I want to add an Authorization Header to the fetch, that contains the Firebase Auth ID Token.

For that, I have set a Session ID Cookie in the +page.sevelte with the Firebase Auth ID Token.

In the +page.server.ts (where the fetch-Request is done), I fetch the cookie and get the Firebase Auth ID Token. Then, I add it as an Auth Header into the fetch-Request to my node.js Backend.

Now my question: Is that approach secure and if not, which other approach would be secure?

Comment: When asking whether something is secure, always be explicit about **what** you want it to be secure against. What is the specific concern you want to be protected against?